# Spring Batch correctly restart uncompleted jobs in clustered environment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, high-availability

I used the following logic to restart the uncompleted jobs on single-node Spring Batch application:

```
public void restartUncompletedJobs() {

    try {
        jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(documetPipelineJob));

        List<String> jobs = jobExplorer.getJobNames();
        for (String job : jobs) {
            Set<JobExecution> runningJobs = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job);

            for (JobExecution runningJob : runningJobs) {
                runningJob.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
                runningJob.setEndTime(new Date());
                jobRepository.update(runningJob);
                jobOperator.restart(runningJob.getId());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Right now I'm trying to make it working on the two-node cluster. Both of the application on every node will be pointed to the shared PostgreSQL database.

Let's consider the following example: I have 2 job instances - the `jobInstance1` is running right now on `node1` and the `jobInstance2` is running on `node2`. `Node1` is restarted for some reason during `jobInstance1` execution. After `node1` restart the spring batch application tries to restart the uncompleted jobs with a logic presented above - it sees that there are 2 uncompleted job instances - `jobInstance1` and `jobInstance2`(which is correctly running on `node2`) and tries to restart both of them. This way instead to restart the only `jobInstance1` - it will restart both `jobInstance1` and `jobInstance2`.. but the `jobInstance2` should not be restarted because it is correctly executing right now on `node2`.

How to correctly restart during the application startup the not completed jobs(before the previous application termination) and prevent the situation when the jobs like `jobInstance2` will be also restarted?

**UPDATED**

This is the solution provided in the answer below:

```
Get the job instances of your job with JobOperator#getJobInstances

For each instance, check if there is a running execution using JobOperator#getExecutions.

2.1 If there is a running execution, move to next instance (in order to let the execution finish either successfully or with a failure)

2.2 If there is no currently running execution, check the status of the last execution and restart it if failed using JobOperator#restart.
```

I have a question regarding #2.1 - will Spring Batch automatically restart uncompleted jobs with a running execution after application restart or do I need to do manual actions to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is not restarting uncompleted jobs. Your logic is taking currently running job executions, setting their status to `FAILED` and restarting them. Your logic should not find *running* executions, it should look for *not* currently running executions, especially failed ones and restart them.

> How to correctly restart the failed jobs and prevent the situation when the jobs like jobInstance2 will be also restarted?

In pseudo code, what you need to do to achieve this is:

1. Get the job instances of your job with `JobOperator#getJobInstances`
2. For each instance, check if there is a running execution using `JobOperator#getExecutions`.

   2.1 If there is a running execution, move to next instance (in order to let the execution finish either successfully or with a failure)

   2.2 If there is no currently running execution, check the status of the last execution and restart it if failed using `JobOperator#restart`.

In your scenario:

- `jobInstance1` should be restarted in step 2.2
- `jobInstance2` should be filtered in step 2.1 since there is a running execution for it on node 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a question - will `JobOperator#getExecutions` distinguish executions which are really running right now from ones, that are in running state in the database, but not running right now due for example to application abnormal termination?

Comment: No, `JobOperator#getExecutions` returns all executions regardless of their status. There is another method called `JobOperator#getRunningExecutions` that returns the running executions. Once you get all executions, you can check their status (and filter the ones that are running in your case).

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472466/spring-batch-restart-persistent-jobs-after-abnormal-termination